# Ubuntu terminal not opening , neither software update , software download and can't reinstall ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 22.04, software-center, reinstall

I am new to linux / ubuntu and today I can't open my terminal nor my software updater and other apps ..I even tried to solve terminal issue by alt+ctrl+f3 and all other keys
but it gives blinking cursor only.I deleted the snap and used flatpak and even delete the original python in ubuntu if that's what caused the problem..I can't reinstall ubuntu as startup disk also doesn't open ..How can I make ubuntu work again or reinstall ubuntu

Comment: Once you deleted python you killed the entire OS. Most of the apps that make up the OS need the version of Python that are its default. What do you mean by start up disk? You install from Live Media. Do you not have the DVD or USB that the OS was installed from in the first place?

Comment: User another computer to create a startup disk (a USB drive/DVD)

Comment: Yes I have the USB that I used to install it..I googled and found startup disk is needed to reinstall ubuntu in os existing ubuntu

Comment: Can I make a new user and reinstall ubuntu or make the old user usable again?

Comment: You can try Synaptic Package Manager and search gnome-terminal. If you have problems with packages, you can find information there.